# Java: detect does user have app installed

Tags: java, android, ios, spring

I have Java REST server. Now when the request comes in and I detect user is using iOS or Android device, is there a way to check if they have app installed.

I am trying to redirect them to app in case they do and app/play store if they don’t

Comment: If the app has registered for a custom URL scheme or regular URL you can open the URL from within the browser if it is installed. This way is it designed to work, without disclosing the installed apps.

Comment: But what if I try to open custom URL scheme and the user does not have the app? What happens then and is it helpful for determining if I should send him to app/play store?

Comment: Nothing happens and the user continues to use the web site.

Comment: Use a universal link, not a custom url scheme. A custom url scheme doesn't use https so nothing happens if the app isn't installed. With a universal link (which is just a regular https link) then the app opens to handle the link if it installed, otherwise they remain in the browser.

Comment: By ‘nothing happens’ you mean what exactly? In my rest app can I try to redirect using custom url scheme and detect ‘nothing happening’ and then open the play/app store link? Sorry this domain really isn’t my strong suit but I know we have custom url schemas in place

Comment: You would use a universal link like `https://our.domain.com/openourapp/`. If the app is installed then the user is prompted to open the app and then your app can do what it likes.  If the app isn't installed then the browser continues to that web page. On that page you can check the browser (Android or iOS) and redirect to the play store / App Store or whatever you like.